# Google YouTube API example not working

Tags: c#, .net, youtube-api

I wish to use Google YouTube API.  I am following this example: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/dotnet#upload_a_video

I have used package manager to download the api (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.YouTube.v3/1.7.0.94-beta) but I see that the code doesn't work as the apis must have changed.

For example the namespaces have changed and the functions in the  code is not recognised.

Does anyone know how to get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot leave a comment because i don't have enough reputation.

Please make sure you're using NuGet to install the latest client library and the related assemblies into your project. See https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/get_started#setup